# PyQt4 gui intermittently disappears/shutsdown

Tags: python, pyqt4

We have developed a PyQt4 gui used on a Linux tester to run and develop test programs developed in Python 2.7. We are having a problem with the gui just 'poofing/disappearing' with no error messages. The only thing that is consistant with the 'poofing' is that it happens when we're looking for operator input by pushing a button (yes, no, continue, cancel,, etc...) which are thoughout the test runs. It will occur intermittently, may not happen for several test runs, then all the sudden, poof. We are pulling our hair out (well, not me, I'm bald) trying to figure this out. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. There is a lot of code and interaction so posting any will be difficult.

Comment: Are you storing the QApplication in a persistent variable that never goes out of scope?

Comment: And are you sure that you're not catching the error message somewhere and not silently ignoring it?

Comment: I am not storing the QApplication and I've tried every way I know of to trap for any errors.

Comment: ``I am not storing the QApplication`` That's your problem right there. The ``QApplication`` NEEDS to be stored in a variable that doesn't go out of scope until the application exits. If you don't, its lifespan is completely undefined behavior, and it can disappear at any arbitrary time.

Comment: [Here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html#qt-and-the-qtconsole) is an example of the 'gotcha' related to this. Your Main Window needs to be kept alive as well, or it could also close at any time.

Comment: If that still doesn't fix it, I recommend adding print statements to every ``except`` clause, and making sure there aren't any ``closeEvents`` calling ``sys.exit`` or somehow propagating themselves up to the main application window.

Comment: Ok, I misspoke, in my main.py, I have the following code 'if not QApplication.instance(): app = QApplication(argv), so does that satisfy the 'variable never going out of scope' issue?

Comment: That should be fine. What about your main window? I would recommend you add a print statement in your ``main`` before ``sys.exit()`` so that you can see if the actual application is terminating, or if your windows are just closing. Might help narrow it down.

Comment: Main just pretty much launches the gui, I have another .py that communicates with the gui. From that file, I launch a worker thread that starts and ends test program runs. To close the gui, there's a Qbutton that performs sys.exit(). The problem is it will just disapper in the middle of a test program run intermittantly.

Comment: Don't call ``sys.exit()`` from inside the GUI code. Properly propagate ``closeEvents`` up the window tree till the main window is closed, at which point Qt will take care of properly cleaning up resources and terminating. Have your ``main`` return ``qApp.exec_()`` after you've called ``show`` on your main window, and then have the following after your ``if __name__ == '__main__'`` in your primary script: ``sys.exit(main())``. Also, you can't interact with the GUI thread from outside of the GUI thread except via ``singals`` and ``slots``. Doing so could cause crashes as well.

Comment: where ``qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)``, and ``main()`` is a function that does your initialization and returns ``qApp.exec_()``

Comment: Ok, taking the exit out of my gui code, not sure where to add close events, but adding sys.exit(main()) to main.py

Comment: Whenever you want to close a window, just call ``self.close()``, which will signal a ``closeEvent`` for that window. If you want to be able to close a parent from a child, simply connect a signal from the child to the ``close`` slot on the parent. You can override the ``closeEvent(event)`` method in the main window to handle any application-level cleanup you want to do.